# Return just ONE string while using Regular Expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, findall

I am working on a simple program that extracts the links from a given website and puts them in a list. Afterwards, the extracted URLs in the "todo"-list get gradually analyzed in the same way.

The main program is working but in the next version, I just want to extract main pages and to ignore undersides (e.g. "www.stackoverflow.com" BUT NOT "www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")

I tried to use the `re.findall` function but as it is a `list` object it destroys the structure of my iterable todo-list.

Is there a possibility to just return a string while using regular expressions?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(handle, 'html.parser')
newlinks = soup.find_all('a')

for link in newlinks:
    todo.append( re.findall('(http://.+)/', link.get('href')) )
```

Comment: Try `todo.extend()` if you don't want a nested list

Comment: Nice, it is working :-) But is there another (maybe smarter) way to cut off the "/blablabla/" than I do? It seems so wrong to me that I use re.findall although there is obviously just one string in link.get('href') that fits my regex.

Comment: If you're using Python 3, the `urllib.parse` module seems like it may have what you want. I've updated my answer with some details.

Comment: @Blckknght Great alternative, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want one match per input string, don't use `findall`, who's very purpose is finding many matches.

Instead, use `re.match(pattern, text)` to get a `match` object. Check that the return value is not `None` (indicating no match found), then call `group(1)` on it to get the matched group.

Note that your pattern is not actually doing what you say you want. If you want to match just initial part of a URL (including the domain, but not the path), you need to exclude slashes from the repeated part of the pattern. I'd use `'(http://[^/]+)/'`. A non-greedy repeat using `+?` instead of `+` would be another option.

If you'd consider abandoning the whole RegEx approach to processing your URL, you might want to try using the `urllib` module instead. Calling `urllib.parse.urlsplit` will break up the URL into the following parts: `<scheme>://<netloc>/<path>?<query>#<fragment>`. (This may be a new function in Python 3, though I'm not certain of that. The `urllib` modules got rearranged quite a bit between versions.)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! I have never used re.match before but I think I've got it now. First I have to create the match object [ mainurl = re.match(regex, link.get('href')) ]. Then I have to make sure that the object is not None [ if mainurl is None: continue ]. And finally I append the string to my todo-list [ todo.append(mainurl.group(1)) ]. Am I right?

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much how I'd do it. If you don't have anything else to do inside the loop, you could reverse the logic of the if and do `if mainurl is not None: todo.append(mainurl.group(1))`

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!